# In .NET WinForms, How to Make a Borderless Form with a Height less than 34?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am using Visual Studio, and created a new Windows Application in C#, that uses WinForms.

I took the Form that was created with the project, and set the **.FormBorderStyle** property to **None**.

I then set the height of the Form to 18.

On the designer everything is well, it does appear as height=18.

But when I run it, the height grows, and changes to 34 for some reason.

I need the form height to be 18, not 34..

What can I do to get it to the Height that I want?

Thank you

Comment: Paste some code so we can test it and provide you satisfying answer

Comment: Your form have any control

Comment: **MajkeloDev:** there is no code since all this was done using Visual Studio's designer.. When I set .FormBorderStyle property to None, it was also done with VS's Designer. **pramod maurya:** I put 3 buttons on that Form, they are small and their size is OK and it doesn't change, but the Form's Height does change.. You have to use Visual Studio to see it..

Comment: you getting height 34 or 38

Comment: I am getting Height=38 pixels, always..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Winforms applies an minimum size constraint to a form that's based on keeping the caption bar usable.  Even if the form doesn't have one, a quirk that most programmers call "bug".

You can however still override the final size by setting the ClientSize property in an event handler for the Load event.  Do beware the need to rescale the window on a machine with a different video DPI setting, you do **not** want to hard-code the size.  Best way is to resize it based on the position of a control.  For example:

```
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        this.ClientSize = new Size(
            this.ClientSize.Width,
            OKButton.Bottom + OKButton.Margin.Bottom
        );
    }
```

With the assumption that a control named OKButton is the bottom one.  Tweak as necessary.

Comment: Thank you Hans! Putting the code to size the form in the Load event handler did solve it. I wonder why putting the code in the Form's Ctor code(after the call to the Initialize() method) did not fix the problem - only when in the Load event handler it helps.. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hans may I ask you one more thing please? When I put the size updating code in the **Load event**, it indeed works very well to resize the form's height. But If I put the same code in the Form's **Ctor**, right after the InitializeComponent(); call, then the resizing oesn't work. Why is that? What is the difference between the Ctor(after the call to InitializeComponent()), and the Form's Load event?

Comment: The minimum size constraint is enforced when the window is created.  The Load event runs after that.

Comment: So there's something that happens after the Ctor ends? Interesting. I thoght that If I put code in the Ctor, after the call to InitializeComponent(), then it's all OK already. Apparently not.. Thank you very much Hans